# How do I create a bootable Ubuntu USB using Trisquel?

Tags: live-usb

Does anyone have experience creating a bootable Ubuntu USB from the Trisquel OS?

I have no access to a Windows or OS X machine.

Comment: Close voters: This is not off-topic. Making a USB flash drive with Ubuntu from Windows and Mac OS X is on-topic. There's no reason it's off-topic for Trisquel (which actually has quite a few users).

Answer (score 5):

[Trisquel](http://trisquel.info/) is sufficiently similar to Ubuntu that you can use essentially the same technique recommended for making an Ubuntu USB on a pre-existing Ubuntu system.

- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Or you can use the Trisquel GNU/Linux instructions for writing a Trisquel ISO to a USB flash drive, **but write the Ubuntu ISO image instead of a Trisquel ISO image**:

- [How to Create a LiveUSB](http://trisquel.info/en/wiki/how-create-liveusb)

The Ubuntu instructions say to search for *Startup Disk Creator* in the Unity dash. The Trisquel instructions say to run it from System Settings (in the GNOME Control Center).

If you don't use a GNOME-based desktop (includes Unity), you can run it directly by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, typing `usb-creator-gtk`, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**If you're using KDE** as your desktop environment, run `usb-creator-kde` instead.

[`usb-creator-gtk`](http://packages.trisquel.info/search?keywords=usb-creator-gtk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [`usb-creator-kde`](http://packages.trisquel.info/search?keywords=usb-creator-kde&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) are available for all versions of Trisquel GNU/Linux. If you don't have them, you can install them with the package manager--for example, in [Add/Remove Applications](https://trisquel.info/en/wiki/installing-updating-and-removing-software). But they are installed by default; it's quite unlikely you don't have them.

#### Here's a summary of what to do once you have successfully launched the utility:

[image: One non-Unity interface's run dialog (this happens to be LXDE).]

Then click *Other*, find the ISO image, and back on the main screen, select which device you want to write it to. (Be careful not to select the wrong one, as this overwrites whatever data are already there.) Click *Make Startup Disk*.

[image]

#### Or use the terminal-based instructions:

The CLI instructions [there](http://trisquel.info/en/wiki/how-create-liveusb) work too. As it says, run:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M;sync
```

- *`/path/to/image.iso`* should be replaced by the actual path. (One way to get this is to drag the ISO image into the terminal window from a file browser window or the desktop.)
- *`X`* should be replaced by the letter (`a`, `b`, `c`, ...) representing the physical disk to which you are writing the image.
- It is *very* important to avoid accidentally writing the image (or any part of it) to the *wrong* drive. Like on Ubuntu, when you run `sudo dd ...` in Trisquel GNU/Linux, there is no protection against a typo that could potentially cause substantial data loss. While an equivalent mistake using the GUI utility (explained above) is possible, the interface makes it somewhat less likely. If you're not already comfortable using the command-line, I recommend the GUI way instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **[MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install)** utility for best results with the least problems, which you can download and install from here: http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install

Comment: That's primarily for creating a USB flash drive with multiple operating systems on it that can be selected between at boot-time. In contrast, here the OP just wants to write an Ubuntu ISO image to a USB flash drive, probably to try or install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Eliah; Ubuntu's own "Startup Disk Creator" whuich is probably included in the Ubuntu-based Trisquel OS might be more straightforward (one-step) solution for this purpose, but for instance I've encountered problems with it sometimes (e.g. with a 2GB USB stick) whereas "MultiSystem" does the same job and much more...